# Lagranges mean value theorem application to get relation in $\le$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I was working on the following problem

> Show that $$\frac{b-a}{\sqrt{1-a^2}}\leq \sin^{-1} b- \sin^{-1} a \leq\frac{b-a}{\sqrt{1-b^2}} $$ $$\text{for } 0<a<b<1. $$

I approached this by using Lagrange's Mean Value theorem on $f(x) = \sin^{-1}x$, on the interval $[a,b]$, but I got the required relation with $<$ instead of $\leq$. How can we get the relation with $\leq$?

Comment: use $\arcsin(x)$ instead of $\sin^{-1}(x)$

Comment: If it's valid with $\lt$ that it's valid with $\le$

Answer (score 0):

Because by Lagrange theorem $$\frac{\arcsin{b}-\arcsin{a}}{b-a}=\arcsin'{c}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-c^2}},$$
where $a<c<b$ and since
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-a^2}}<\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-c^2}}<\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-b^2}},$$
we are done!

Comment: I think he meant $\arcsin x$ not $\frac{1}{\sin x}$

Comment: @Andrei Thank you! I fixed.